# Change a string of two html files from javaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a list in one file html called "filed1":

```
<ul> 
    <li>Nombre:<a class="boton" onclick=move() title="Caja">Caja</a><br> 
    <FONT SIZE=2>Fecha: 21/12/1994</font></font></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to change a string in other html "filed2":

```
<a id="logo-header2">
    <h1>
        <span class="site-name" id="element">Details</span><br>
    </h1>
</a>
```

Using Java Script:

```
function move() {
    mywindow = window.open("file2.html");
    mywindow.document.getElementById("element").innerHTML="Changed");
}
```

But there is an error which says that `mywindow.document.getElementById("element")` is NULL, why? The id element exists in the other window. Is there another way to change the string?

Comment: You're closing your `<font>` tag twice (`</font></font>`) and have a stray bracket after `.innerHTML="Changed")`

Comment: Looks like you have an extra paranthesis after "Changed".

Comment: Wow... `<font>`? It's been a while.... :)

Comment: Also: `onclick=move()` => `onclick="move()"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to retrieve the DOM element before the window is loaded.

Try following

```
mywindow.onload = function() {
    mywindow.document.getElementById("element").innerHTML="Changed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @nikhil mentioned, mywindow is undefined when you're calling it, and you'll need to place your code into something triggered by the `onload` event.

Another approach you can try is perhaps passing the string as a variable in the url, like so:

```
function move(){
    window.open("file2.html?str=Changed");
}
```

And then in file2.html, try something that runs on page load:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var str = $_GET('str');
    document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = str;
};

function $_GET(q){
    var $_GET = {};
    if(document.location.toString().indexOf('?') !== -1){
        var query = document.location
                       .toString()
                       .replace(/^.*?\?/, '')//Get the query string
                       .replace(/#.*$/, '')//and remove any existing hash string
                       .split('&');
        for(var i=0, l=query.length; i<l; i++){
           var aux = decodeURIComponent(query[i]).split('=');
           $_GET[aux[0]] = aux[1];
        }
    }
    return $_GET[q];
}
```

The $_GET function I included is just for getting query string parameters, and function much like $_GET[] in php.